# git pull using putty asks for password

Tags: git, batch-file, passwords, putty, pull

I want to make a bat file which runs a git pull command. 
I have the following .bat file:

```
ssh.cmd
cd [path to my putty installation]
Start putty.exe -ssh [path to server] -l [username] -pw [password] -m C:[path to text file]/update.txt
```

and a txt file with the following code

```
cd [to domain where i want gitt pull to be executed]
git pull https://[username]@bitbucket.org/[username]/[project].git
```

This works, but putty asks for a password for the git. however, i cant put it in. 
How do i pass the git password with the command? or make the password input on putty work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use credential helper, which will cache credentials after you will enter it for the first time. For more details see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github) answer